# Github GraphQl get REPOSITORY subscriber count and the list of subscribers

Tags: android, github, graphql, github-graphql

I am using the following to search repositories by query name "android"

```
{
  search(query: "android", type: REPOSITORY, first: 50) {
    repositoryCount
    edges {

      node {
        ... on Repository {
          id
          name
          description
          forkCount
          owner{
            avatarUrl
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to get the REPOSITORY subscriber count and the list of subscribers

Thanks In advance :)

Comment: Do you mean the number of people who [watch](https://help.github.com/articles/watching-and-unwatching-repositories/) the repository ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel In the github V3 search there is subscribersUrl Links... something like that

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [watchers](https://help.github.com/articles/watching-and-unwatching-repositories/), the terminology used in v3 is `subscribers`, check [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/watching/#watching) :

```graphql
{
  search(query: "android", type: REPOSITORY, first: 50) {
    repositoryCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          nameWithOwner
          watchers(first: 100) {
            totalCount
            nodes{
              login
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20search(query%3A%20%22android%22%2C%20type%3A%20REPOSITORY%2C%20first%3A%2050)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20repositoryCount%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nameWithOwner%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20watchers(first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20login%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: That seems more accurate than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

The [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) itself has no notion of "subscriber" (at most, the [number of clones, over the last 14 days](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/traffic/#clones))

GraphQL itself has the [notion of subcription](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/subscriptions/), as [described here](https://github.com/facebook/graphql/blob/master/rfcs/Subscriptions.md), but they are not for the "repository".